# Radio button Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, radio-button

I am developing an quiz based website using rails, need help with this.
I am generating a form with all questions and options. I need user to select only one of the options and submit.
The code is as follows:

```
<%=form_tag(action: "evaluation", method: "post", class: "nifty_form") do %>
<%= @exam.name %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
<%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
<% if @exam.questions.any?%>
    <%@exam.questions.each do |question|%>
        <p><%= label_tag(question.id, question.content)%></p>
            <ul>
            <% if question.options.any?%>
                <% question.options.each do |option|%>
                    <li><%= radio_button_tag(option.id, option.content)%> <%= option.content%></li>
                <% end %>
            <%else%>
                <p>No options</p>   
            <% end %>
            </ul>
    <% end %>
<%else%>
    <p>No questions</p>
<% end %>
<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>
```

Now the problem that I am facing is that the radio buttons thus rendered are like that all can be selected for a questions and also they cannot be unchecked once selected. 
Please help.

Comment: You mean radio button must can be unchecked?

Comment: set the required attribute to true for the radio button tag.

Comment: @penguin I mean that if i have four options for a question, i need only one of them to be selectable, but in this case all can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Radio button name should be unique for all options. If you have different name for each radio button it belongs to each group.

Try this:

```
<% question.options.each do |option|%>
<li><%= radio_button_tag(question.id, option.id)%> <%= option.content%></li>
<% end %>
```

Comment: the name is unique already as they are derived from question Id and option Id.